# Are there any XML Editors with FTP and file-tree browsing combined?

Tags: xml, ftp, text-editor, replace

Are there any (free preferably) XML Editors combined with

- FTP and
- file-tree browsing
- Project wide find+Replace

I.e A bit like what Dreamweaver MX is but with fancier XML capabilities /XSLT /XSD

Perhaps even DW does this...im still on an older version.

I'd like to keep a smooth flow between

- find-edit-view-upload

any ideas?

---

Background: I have converted most of the html files of my legacy site into XML (which match the directory structure of my 'public docs' folder). Part of a step towards turning it into completely dynamic data via MVC /Front Controller Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is by far the best XML editting suite I have seen and should be very useful for what you are attempting.  It has a very good XPath editor and good support for creating and using XSDs. It has a simple FTP client.

On the downside it is a pricey application.